# Calculating Bandwidth(Sent bytes and receive bytes always return 0)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I read this [article](http://pastebin.com/f371375d6) , I want to get sent bytes and receive bytes for all process, but sent bytes and receive bytes of all process always return 0;
Here is my code:

```
namespace Network
{
    public class NetworkTraffic
    {
        private List<PerformanceCounter> listBytesSentPerformanceCounter;
        private List<PerformanceCounter> listBytesReceivedPerformanceCounter;
        //private PerformanceCounter bytesSentPerformanceCounter;
        //private PerformanceCounter bytesReceivedPerformanceCounter;

        public NetworkTraffic()
        {
            listBytesSentPerformanceCounter = new List<PerformanceCounter>();
            listBytesReceivedPerformanceCounter = new List<PerformanceCounter>();
            List<string> listInstanceName = GetInstanceName();

            foreach (string str in listInstanceName)
            {
                PerformanceCounter bytesSentPerformanceCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
                PerformanceCounter bytesReceivedPerformanceCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
                bytesSentPerformanceCounter.CategoryName = ".NET CLR Networking 4.0.0.0";
                bytesSentPerformanceCounter.CounterName = "Bytes Sent";
                bytesSentPerformanceCounter.InstanceName = str;
                bytesSentPerformanceCounter.ReadOnly = false;
                listBytesSentPerformanceCounter.Add(bytesSentPerformanceCounter);

                bytesReceivedPerformanceCounter.CategoryName = ".NET CLR Networking 4.0.0.0";
                bytesReceivedPerformanceCounter.CounterName = "Bytes Received";
                bytesReceivedPerformanceCounter.InstanceName = str;
                bytesReceivedPerformanceCounter.ReadOnly = false;
                listBytesReceivedPerformanceCounter.Add(bytesReceivedPerformanceCounter);
            }
        }

        //public float GetBytesSent()
        //{
        //    float bytesSent = bytesSentPerformanceCounter.RawValue;

        //    return bytesSent;
        //}

        //public float GetBytesReceived()
        //{
        //    float bytesReceived = bytesReceivedPerformanceCounter.RawValue;

        //    return bytesReceived;
        //}

        private static List<string> GetInstanceName()
        {
            // Used Reflector to find the correct formatting:
            string assemblyName = GetAssemblyName();
            if ((assemblyName == null) || (assemblyName.Length == 0))
            {
                assemblyName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
            }
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(assemblyName);
            for (int i = 0; i < builder.Length; i++)
            {
                switch (builder[i])
                {
                    case '/':
                    case '\\':
                    case '#':
                        builder[i] = '_';
                        break;
                    case '(':
                        builder[i] = '[';
                        break;

                    case ')':
                        builder[i] = ']';
                        break;
                }
            }

            List<string> listInstanceName = new List<string>();
            Process[] listProcess = Process.GetProcesses();
            string InstanceName;
            foreach (Process pro in listProcess)
            {
                InstanceName = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                     "{0}[{1}]",
                                     builder.ToString(),
                                     pro.Id);
                listInstanceName.Add(InstanceName);
            }
            return listInstanceName;
        }
        private static string GetAssemblyName()
        {
            string str = null;
            Assembly entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
            if (entryAssembly != null)
            {
                AssemblyName name = entryAssembly.GetName();
                if (name != null)
                {
                    str = name.Name;
                }
            }
            return str;
        }


        public static void Main()
        {
            NetworkTraffic networkTraffic = new NetworkTraffic();

            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
                    webRequest.Method = "GET";

                    using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
                    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                    }
                    //Console.WriteLine("Bytes sent: {0}", networkTraffic.GetBytesSent());
                    //Console.WriteLine("Bytes received: {0}", networkTraffic.GetBytesReceived());
                    foreach (PerformanceCounter send in networkTraffic.listBytesSentPerformanceCounter)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Instance name: " + send.InstanceName + " Sent: " + send.RawValue);
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone can help me resolve this.

Comment: How many of those processes do you expect to use the CLR?  Well, clearly none.  Find better performance counters with Perfmon.exe.  You'll find useful ones in the Network Adapter and Network Interface category.  Like "Current Bandwidth".

Comment: Thank for your reply.
I can get all CategoryName base on PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories and use CategoryName. In my case, I want to get all the network activity data in Resource monitor, so what CategoryName I have to choose.

Comment: I want to get send bytes/ receive bytes per process. Do you know how I can do it.